# How to suppress letter-numbering in subfloat?

Tags: floats, captions

I know, subfloat might not be the go-to-tool for multiple pictures. I reckoned subfigure might be better, but I just copied and filled the code already, hence I'm not inclined to rewrite it all. I don't really gasp the code either, so if u were to solve this problem for me I'd be thankful. 
As mentioned I just want the letters (a), (b), (c), ... beneath each picture to be turned off. According to the code below:

```latex
\begin{figure}[h]

\centering 

\subfloat[subtitle]{\label{}%
  \fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth] {path}}}\quad
...

\caption*{\textsl{\small title}}

\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome! The purpose of `\subfloat` is to add a subcaption with its label; just include the picture if you don't want them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Probably I have to specify: I want to place figures side to side. I figured, this ain't possible with the normal figure option, so I included subfloat. That's my reasoning.

Comment: That's what leads me still to the described problem.

Comment: Two figures side by side with separate captions?

Comment: well to be clear 2 pictures side by side and 10 below (10 x 2) and each with a subtitle